# Why does lapply(file_list, function(i){} not work?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, lapply

Why does this not work? Thanks for help.
I got this message.

> [.data.frame(true, rep(NA_integer_, length(condition)))

```
set.seed(42)
file_list<-ceiling(runif(16,0,50))
library(dplyr)
a = 350
b = 250
Track <- lapply(file_list, function(T1) {
  if_else (T1[2] > 0, 
           round(((acos((T1[1]-a)/sqrt(((T1[1]-a)^2)+((T1[2]-b)^2))))
                  *(180/pi)),
                 digits = 0), 
           round(((-acos((T1[1]-a)/sqrt(((T1[1]-a)^2)+((T1[2]-b)^2))))
                  *(180/pi))+360,
                 digits = 0)
  )
})
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding how lapply works- it is taking a single element at a time from file_list and doing an operation it.